# ffmpeg to combine two mov files from iPhone

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine two videos recorded on an iPhone into one file with ffmpeg.

I've tried everything I could find and I can't get anything to work right.

My current line is

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:output.mov|capturedvideo.MOV' -vcodec copy -acodec copy output2.mov
```

This currently won't work. The end result needs to be played on an iPhone.

Comment: By the way, superuser.com may be a better forum for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are not transcoding, you cannot concatenate two mp4 containers just like that. See [this page](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files).

In essence, you have to convert the files (without transcoding) to MPEG transport streams:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

You'll need a recent version of `ffmpeg`. Try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` (on Ubuntu Linux) or `brew update; brew install ffmpeg` (on Mac OS X)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'll try this in a second. Does it matter if they aren't mp4s?

Comment: @JasonStallings The link suggests re-muxing if you're using the [concat protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat). The same link has an example for the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) which will not require the additional step.

Comment: I get Unrecognized option 'c' :(

Then when I remove it I get Unrecognized option 'bsf:v

This is a bad sign isn't it?

Comment: I tried your commands which worked but I lost the sound for some reason. Is there something in there which strips the sound?